# StructureMap 4.0.0 injecting concrete instance

Tags: c#, structuremap, structuremap4

I've recently updated structuremap and discovered that you can't inject concrete instances to properties anymore using old syntax. For example the code is no longer valid:

```
public class IdentityRegistry : Registry
{
      public IdentityRegistry()
      {
          For<IAuthenticationManager>().Use(manager => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication);

          Policies
                 .FillAllPropertiesOfType<IAuthenticationManager>()
                 .Use(manager => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication);
      }
}
```

How to make the code work with previous effect?

Comment: This is still working using StructureMap 4.0.1.318.